# Make User admin in appcelerator arrow app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow, arrowdb

I have created an app in appcelerator arrow db using free subscription. When I published this app from appcelerator studio as user got created for this app. But this user is not admin and when I try to do bulk_delete it doesn't allow me to do that.

I followed steps to make user admin but when I go to my app in https://platform.appcelerator.com/ it only shows me DEV of my app and nor PROD. PROD is locked and asks me to pay.

Is this any way to make this user admin?

Please help..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a free trial account, you do not have the ability to release your app into Production. That is why your seeing it "locked" as you describe.

Any user created can be changed to Admin from within the dashboard (or even from the command line). Open up your dashboard as jonathan-wheat describes and click on the existing user. This will open up the details for that user. There is a radio group for Admin. Make sure this is set to 'true'.

By default, users created for you should be admin already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the locked Production selection, but to change a user to admin - click Apps | [your application] | Arrow (on the left) | click your app name again | Manage Data (on the left) | Users (on the right)

From here you can create a new user (button at the top right), or select a user and change the Admin radio button to Yes.

Hope that helps.
-Jon

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your response. I am aware of process which you described. But for me while selecting app it shows me app for Development. So users for Development are shown and not for Production.